# Debugging in PyCharm with using Vagrant VM connection - cannot import name to_string

Tags: python, pycharm

I've encountered an issue where I cannot debug in PyCharm connecting through Vagrant to the VM.  This has worked fine for projects up until now.  The VM image was recently updated so I'm wondering if that has had an effect.  I can run programs in "run" mode, just not debug mode.  Here's the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 25, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle import pydevd_vars
File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 21, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_utils import to_string
ImportError: cannot import name to_string
```

Here are the different commands used to run the programs - the first one is debug mode, the second is normal mode

```
ssh://vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222/usr/bin/python -u /home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client '0.0.0.0' --port 32807 --file /home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py /vagrant/project/project_test.py::ProjectTest true

ssh://vagrant@127.0.0.1:2222/usr/bin/python -u /home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py /vagrant/project/project_test.py::ProjectTest true
```

Any ideas what why `to_string` is found in normal mode but not debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to delete the /home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers directory and restart PyCharm and vagrant to regenerate the directory.